# Oracle : Get average count for last 30 business days

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle version **11g**.

My table has records similar to these.

```
calendar_date   ID   record_count
25-OCT-2017      1   20
25-OCT-2017      2   40
25-OCT-2017      3   60
24-OCT-2017      1   70
24-OCT-2017      2   50
24-OCT-2017      3   10
20-OCT-2017      1   35
20-OCT-2017      2   60
20-OCT-2017      3   90
18-OCT-2017      1   80
18-OCT-2017      2   50
18-OCT-2017      3   45
```

i.e for each `ID`, there is one  record count for a given calendar day. The days are **NOT** continuous, i.e there may be missing records for weekends/holidays etc. On such days, there will not  be records available for any ID. However on working days there are  entries available for each ID .

I **need to get the average** record count for last `30 business days`  for each id

I want an output like this. ( Don't go by the values. It is just a sample )

```
ID  avg_count_last_30
1    150
2    130
3    110
```

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to do this. I thought of using `RANGE BETWEEN` , `ROWS BETWEEN` etc , but unsure it would work.

Off course a query like this won't help as there are holidays in between.

```
select id, AVG(record_count) FROM mytable 
where calendar_date between SYSDATE - 30 and SYSDATE - 1
group by id;
```

what I need is something like

```
select id , AVG(record_count) FROM mytable 
    where calendar_date between last_30th_business_day and last_business_day
    group by id;
```

`last_30th_business_day`  will be  `count(DISTINCT business_days )` starting from most recent business day going backwards till I count 30.

`last_business_day`  will be  *most recent business day*

Would like to know experts opinion on this and  best approach.

Comment: How do you get holidays dates? exluding week-ends is not too difficult but you will need a table containing holidays dates as a reference.

Comment: You need is more about specific calender driven approach. You must create a Holiday table and use it in your query.

Comment: Do you have **one** record for each business day?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no holiday table. I need to purely go by record count. However we are making sure that there will be records for  at least last 30 business days on the day of calculation

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : Yes. there will be just one record per id for each business day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment try this one:

```
WITH mytable (calendar_date, ID, record_count) AS (
    SELECT TO_DATE('25-10-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 1, 20 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('25-10-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 2, 40 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('25-10-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 3, 60 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('24-10-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 1, 70 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('24-10-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 2, 50 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('24-10-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 3, 10 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('20-10-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 1, 35 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('20-10-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 2, 60 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('20-10-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 3, 90 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('18-10-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 1, 80 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('18-10-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 2, 50 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('18-10-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 3, 45 FROM dual),
t AS (
    SELECT calendar_date, ID, record_count,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY calendar_date desc) AS RN
    FROM mytable)
SELECT ID, AVG(RECORD_COUNT) 
FROM t
WHERE rn <= 30
group by ID;
```

Comment: I need to try this..will let u know. Actually this is a component of my large query which has several other computations. Let's see how they all work together.

Comment: Thanks..this works for even cases where records are available for less than 30 days.